# fatal-error while loading fetching iimage from sdcard specific folder

Tags: android, imageview, android-sdcard, fatal-error

I have image name in sqlite database table. while iterating cursor getting image name and trying to fetch image one by one to display. TableLayouts,TableRow,ImageView are created Programmatically. After reading some image fatal exception occur and application crashed. Give any suggestion to solve problem.

```
    Cursor cursor = GlobalClass.db.getCursor("FBPMGPT as a,FBMRMMT as b", new String[] {"a.MenuGroup,a.Description,b.ItemCode,b.ItemName,b.ItemRate"},"a.MenuGroup=b.MenuGroup and b.RestaurantCode='" + GlobalClass.RESTAURANT_CODE + "'", "a.MenuGroup,b.ItemName");
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    TableLayout tablelayout = new TableLayout(thisActivity)
    if(!cursor.isAfterLast())
    {
    do
    {
    TableRow tablerow = new TableRow(thisActivity);

    ////////////Image to item get here based on item code////////////////////
    imageView = getItemImageView(thisActivity, thisContext, cursor.getString(2));
    imageView.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
    imageView.setTag(cursor.getString(2));
    imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border);
    tablerow.addView(imageView);

    tablelayout.addView(tablerow);

     } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    cursor.close();
    }
     public ImageView getItemImageView(Activity activity, Context context, String s)
        {
      String Foldername="ImageFolder"
      String s2="";
      ImageView imageview;
      String s1 = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/"+Foldername+"/"+s.trim().toString();
       if (fileExists(s1+".JPG"))
          s2 = s1+".JPG".toString();
      else if (fileExists(s1+".PNG"))
          s2 = s1+".PNG".toString();
      else
          s2 = "";  
     imageview = new ImageView(context);
     if (!s2.equals(""))
     {
        Bitmap bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(s2);
        Bitmap bm=bm.createScaledBitmap(bitmap,100,100, true);
        imageview.setImageBitmap(bm);
     } else
     {
         imageview.setImageResource(R.drawable.noimagefound);
         imageview.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
     }
      imageview.setMaxWidth(GlobalClass.BUTTON_GLOBAL_ITEM_IMAGE_WIDTH);
      imageview.setMaxHeight(GlobalClass.BUTTON_GLOBAL_ITEM_IMAGE_HEIGHT);
      return imageview;
    }
```

Comment: What error are you getting (stack trace)? Sounds like a possible memory problem, but please include code or error messages.

Comment: Please find the attached code